# Facebook webhook for leadgen - Can't retrieve Facebook Lead Ads

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I follow this Facebook's guide:
https://www.facebook.com/marketingdevelopers/videos/883648801749520/

I set up successfully all these steps:

1. In the "developers.facebook.com/apps/APP-ID", I add "webhooks" product and create subscription to page and subscribe to leadgen, In addition, I verified my callback_url successfully
2. I create a new page that used Facebook Javascript SDK and I send a post request using FB.api with the user page access token to the page subscribed_apps and the API returns me "{success:true}", I double checked if that worked with the Facebook graph by sending the same request just with GET method and it return me and object that looks like that: 
   `{ "data": [ { "link": "https://www.my-url.com/", "name": "my app name", "id": "my app id" } ] }`

Now, all I had to do is to send a test to my lead ad and get an update notification to my callback_url which is

```
https://www.my-domain.com/admin/webhook
```

I tried 2 different ways, the first is from my app subscription, I don't get any error but nothing happened
[image]

the second way was with "Lead ads testing tool"

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lead-ads-testing

and I'm receiving an error with error code 301 that says "rejected"

[image]

Comment: Hi @Ilan, I was setting up the webhooks and got stuck. Unfortunately, I can't view the video which you have added in the link, as it is not available. I have also added a webhook and subscribed to the page as you have mentioned in point 1.
But, in the second screenshot which you have shared, I am not able to view any webhook subscription for the selected page. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after hours of searching I found this answer:
[Facebook Messenger webhook setup, but not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803570/facebook-messenger-webhook-setup-but-not-triggered)

and I send curl to my server and also got 301,
so I realized that the issue was with my htaccess file, I could not fix it so I move the webhook.php to my main domain and now it works!